# Rails changing date formatting upon insertion into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite, date

I need to compare today's date, which is 'calculated' as today :

```
 time=Time.now
 today=time.day.to_s+'/'+time.month.to_s+'/'+time.year.to_s
```

where today would look like:

```
"21/4/2015"
```

But when that example today goes into the db, sqlite auto-formats it to look like:

```
2015-04-21
```

But, I need to check whether today (declared above) is equal to the attribute from the db (post conversion). This, invariably, returns false, because whilst they are the same thing, the strings aren't equal. This breaks the logic of my program.

Is there a way to convert today (declared above) to the same format as what happens to it when it is put into the db? i.e preprocess it, so that the logic holds and the equality check would return true.

i.e

```
today.someMethod==Model.date => true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strftime`](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime):

```
time = Time.now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
# => "21/04/2015"
```

Here:

> %Y - Year with century (can be negative, 4 digits at least).
>
> %m - Month of the year, zero-padded (01..12).
>
> %d - Day of the month, zero-padded (01..31).

Also, if you're using Rails and want to check if a particular datetime falls under today's date then you can use `today?` like this for example:

```
MyModel.create(:attrib => 'value') # assuming you have no entry in my_models table yet.
MyModel.first.created_at.today? #=> true
```

Comment: Cool man! I switched around the day and years because that's what Rails was outputting, and also chucked on a .to_s on the date format being outputted from the rails db object, but all working now. Appreciate that :)